# acer aspire 4740 driver

Tags: aspire

how to istall intel graphic card driver in acer aspire 4740

Comment: are you facing any problems with your display or graphics acceleration? intel graphics works out of the box in most cases

Answer (score 2):

As far as im aware, intel does not provide third party drivers for linux and your graphics will be powered by the generic drivers from the kernel.

Edit

Ive done a bit of investigating, intel graphics drivers for linux are already in the kernel so there shouldnt be anything else to download. They do provide source code for development drivers, if you are inclined to compile them yourself for whatever reason. More info here: http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/cs-010512.htm